# I dont understand the scope of try catches when it comes to java sockets

Tags: java, networking

I am in year 13 and have decided for my computer science coursework to make a small chat program using java. I have had to learn the networking aspect from scratch and my teachers are unfamiliar with it so they struggle to answer my questions. I have a client program and a server program and they communicate via a socket I creat, my issue is I dont understand the effect the try catches are having on my code. I am really fascinated with networking and thats why I chose it knowing full well it would be a challange, Ill leave my code below and the error I am having. If you could give me any tips on how I can solve my problem and also make my code 'better' that would be absolutely fantastic. Also please take into account I have only known java for around a year now and am still a novice futher more this is my first question on stack overflow!. Many thanks!

Client Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package oclient;

import  java.net.*;
import  java.io.*;
import com.dosse.upnp.UPnP;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author sgmud
 */
public class CClient {
    public Socket CSocket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public BufferedReader in;
    
    
    public int GetPort(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the port number");
        int PortNum = scan.nextInt();
        return PortNum;
    }
    
    public String GetAddress(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the IP address of the host");
        String Address = scan.nextLine();
        return Address;
    }
    
    public void StartConnection(String ip, int port){
        try{
            CSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(CSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CSocket.getInputStream()));
        }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    public void sendMessage(String msg){ 
        
        //String Response;
        
        
        out.println(msg);  // outputs message
        

        //try{
        //    Response = in.readLine();
        //}catch(IOException e){
        //    System.out.println("ERROR");
        //}
        //System.out.println(Response);
        //return Response; 
        
    
    }

    public String receveMessage(){
        String Response = "IfYouReadThisThetryCatchIsNotWorkingHowYouIntendItTo";
        try{
            Response = in.readLine();
            
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            
        }finally{
            System.out.println(Response);
            return Response;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public void convosation(){  // method will keep letting you send a message untill you stop
        CClient client = new CClient();
        while (true){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Type QUIT to end the convosation or press any key to send a message");
            String qit = scan.nextLine();
            if("QUIT".equals(qit)){
                client.STOP();
            }
            else{
                client.sendMessage(client.Message()); // Runs the send message method with the output from the Message method
                client.receveMessage();
            }
        }       
    }

    public String Message(){                   
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("please enter a mesasge to be sent");
            String message = scan.nextLine();
           
            return message;
        
    }
    
    public void STOP(){
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            CSocket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
    
    /**
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CClient client = new CClient(); // Making a new client class
        client.StartConnection(client.GetAddress(), client.GetPort()); // runs the startConnection method but runs the Get address and Get port method first so the Start connection method has the IP and Port number 
        client.convosation();
        // client.STOP(); // runs the stop method which will terminate the server
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Server Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package oserver;

import  java.net.*;
import  java.io.*;
import com.dosse.upnp.UPnP;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author sgmud
 */
public class SServer { // Server Class 
    public ServerSocket SSocket;
    public Socket CSocket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public BufferedReader in;
    
    public int GetPort(){ // Gets port number for socket to be set listening to
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the port number");
        int PortNum = scan.nextInt();
        return PortNum;
        
    }    
    
    public void start(int port) { // Starts the server with the collected port
        try{
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            UPnP.openPortTCP(port);
            SSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            CSocket = SSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Server Connected");
            
            out = new PrintWriter(CSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CSocket.getInputStream()));
            
            
            String input;
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null){
                if(".".equals(input)){
                    out.println("goodbye");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    out.println(input);
                }
            }
            
            
            
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
        }   
    }

    public void stop(){ // Will close all connections
        try{
            //in.close();
            out.close();
            CSocket.close();
            SSocket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        SServer server = new SServer(); // Creat new server class
        server.start(server.GetPort()); // Starts the server with the port number
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Error (This is on client side):

```
run:
Please enter the IP address of the host
0.0.0.0
please enter the port number
6666
Type QUIT to end the convosation or press any key to send a message
h
please enter a mesasge to be sent
hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.PrintWriter.println(String)" because "this.out" is null
    at oclient.CClient.sendMessage(CClient.java:54)
    at oclient.CClient.convosation(CClient.java:94)
    at oclient.CClient.main(CClient.java:125)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to not be try-catch but lack of error handling.

If we assume the commented-out code in sendMessage to be actually operational:

```
    try{
        Response = in.readLine();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
    System.out.println(Response);
    return Response;
```

then what happens if there is an exception from code executing inside the 'try' is that you print out ERROR, and that is all you do.

Execution then carries on 'down the page' and you attempt to print out, and return, the value of Response.  But Response was never assigned; the assignment inside the try-block never completed.  So Response still has the value it had on entry to sendMessage, which may be null.

If you're going to catch the error-exception inside sendMessage, then (a) you need to write code to handle the error, and (b) sendMessage needs a way to indicate failure.  Maybe you make the function return the response for success, null for failure.  The caller then has to be aware that a null return is possible.

```
try{
    Response = in.readLine();
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    return null;
}
System.out.println(Response);
return Response;
```

Alternatively, you could *not* catch the error there, but allow it to propagate out.  That is, the caller of sendMessage has to be aware that sendMessage can throw an exception, and either handle it, or let it propagate out.  The decision of where it is appropriate to handle the exception is something that needs to be considered on a wider basis than just one method.

Incidentally, many postings on Stack Overflow show the same pattern of exception handling by 'print and continue'.  It's rarely a good way.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, much appriciated. I dont currently have a good understanding on handling exeption handling so Ill make sure I work on that.

Comment: Appropriate error handling is often one of the more complicated parts of programming - it's often harder to write that than the 'happy path' (a piece of professional jargon for you!) through the code.